# Getting the if statement in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to make an if statement in HAML and it just keeps erroring out. Any ideas how I can get this to work. Here's what I have been trying:

```
f.text_field :description, class: 'field-input', @payment_type == 'flat' ? 'currency-format'=> true : 'currency-format' => false
```

I've defined payment_type, but it is erroring out putting red lines on the

```
=> //RUBY EXPECTED :
```

and

```
true : //EXPECTED :/ or ruby injection
```

Am I doing this right?

Basically I am wanting to say:

```
If payment_type ==flat
    currency-format = true
else
    currency-format = false
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
currency_format = @payment_type == 'flat' ? true : false
f.text_field :description, 'currency-format' => currency_format, class: 'field-input'
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the conditional logic into the value assignment for currency-format:

```
f.text_field :description, class: 'field-input', 'currency-format' => (@payment_type == 'flat')
```

Comment: Dude, down voting for the sake of being first is an ugly move

Comment: Yeah, had a duplicate key. Leave a comment next time down voting. After 13k reps that should be obvious. @Oleg's answer is correct tho

Comment: Yes it's correct but may need a longer explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Set the value for `currency-format` to `(@payment_type == 'flat')`, which is `true` or `false`.

```
f.text_field :description, class: 'field-input', 'currency-format' => (@payment_type == 'flat')
```